# Problema con python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un programa que tu metas un numero y detecte si es par o impar, si es par lo divida por 2 y si es impar lo multiplique por 3 y sume 1, y que cuando el numero resultante sea igual a 1 terminar el proceso. Pero no consigo que esto funcione :)

```py
n = input("Enter a number: ")
n = int(n)

for i in range(100):
    while n % 2 == 0:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0

for i in range(100):
    if a == 1:
        print(n/2)
        n = n/2
        break
    if a == 0:
        print(3*n + 1)
        n = 3*n + 1
        break
    if n == 1:
        print('Cicle compleeted!')
        break
```

Comment: Buen día, ignorando por un momento los `for` que creo que no tienen nada que ver con lo que intentas hacer, me gustaría entender lo que quieres hacer, la entrada del programa debería ser un número, ¿Ese número es siempre entero o puede ser flotante (Con punto decimal)? Luego se determina si el número es par o no, si es par se hace la siguiente operación `resultado = num * 2` y si es impar `resultado = (num * 3) + 1`, ¿Es correcto? Ahora, ¿Si resultado es `1` entonces terminar el proceso? Es decir, ¿Para que el resultado sea `1` el número debe ser `0`?

Comment: Ahora, si el resultado no es `1` y el proceso no termina ¿Qué debería suceder? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información faltante para que podamos entender lo que quieres hacer y ayudarte

Comment: Pon en el título _qué es lo que no funciona_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo que intento es que al introducir un numero natural (ni decimal ni negativo), el programa lea que ese numero es par o impar. si es par: numero = 3*numero+1 si es impar: numero = numero/2
Pero quiero que este proceso se repita hasta que el numero sea = 1

Comment: Las operaciones que pusiste en el comentario son diferentes a lo que explicas en la pregunta,  Multiplicar es `*`, Dividir es `/` ¿Cuál es la información correcta?

Comment: la de la pregunta esta mal perdoname la correcta es la del codigo y la del comentario anterior

Comment: Ok, por favor edita tu pregunta (En la parte inferior hay un url que dice "editar") y corrige el texto de la pregunta para que otros usuarios puedan entender la pregunta de forma correcta. Si el valor de `n` es `1` al inicio, ¿Debe hacer `n*3 + 1` o inmediatamente terminar el programa? Si el valor de `n` es `2` ¿Debe hacer `n/2` y como el resultado es `1` terminar el programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es conocido como "La conjetura de Collatz", y dice que para cualquier valor de entrada, el método siempre llegara a 1. No está demostrado, pero no hay contraejemplos.

Una solución:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n //= 2
    else:
        n = n * 3 + 1
    print(f"  {n}")
```

Ingresado el número, entramos en un ciclo mientras el número no llegue a 1.

En cada iteración revisamos el número. Si es par, lo dividimos por dos usando el operador `//`, que significa división entera.

Si no es par, aplicamos la formula `3*n+1`.

En cada iteración, imprimimos el nuevo número.

#### Demo

```
Enter a number: 23
  70
  35
  106
  53
  160
  80
  40
  20
  10
  5
  16
  8
  4
  2
  1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, quiera probar la conjetura por mi mismo pero aun soy muy novato